# Android App - Show GSM Cell ID in TextView

Tags: android

I have simple question,

How to make a simple app in which someone can press button and in textview will show the GSM Cell ID?

P.S.: I'm new in this kind of programming.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cell id'? The id of the Button or TextView?

Comment: Might [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getCid%28%29) be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Learn how to write basic android app

2) Write a basic app with a button and a label

3) When the button is clicked request a cell location (check google's documentation)

4) Once you have a cell location extract the cell id (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/GsmCellLocation.html#getCid%28%29) and put it on the label

Answer (score 1):

by using `TelephoneManager` you can get that here is an example:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String simNo = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

**edit:**
don't forget to add this permission to your manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```